# Search handler in a grid

Tags: xaml, controller, maui

I was wondering if it is possible to have maui [search handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/search?view=net-maui-8.0) in `<Grid>`.  Instead of having it in a tool bar, I want to have its functionality as a part of an input form, where I can type in some letters and it shows contents that include the letters with data binding. I know that there is "Picker", but it does not have an input bar and when there are a lot of data, it is not useful that you need you look for what you want from a long list.

Currently have:

```
<Shell.SearchHandler>
   <local: ProductSearchHandler ...>
</Shell.SearchHandler>
```

Hoping to have something like

```
<Grid>
   <Label Text="Product">
   <local: ProductSearchHandler ...>
</Grid>
```

I found ComboBox from a third party website, but I want to use maui built-in functionalities as possible.

Comment: use a [SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/searchbar?view=net-maui-8.0)

Answer (score 1):

From document [.NET MAUI Shell search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/search?view=net-maui-8.0), we could find that `SearchHandler` is the designed to be added at the top of the page.

And it is added inner side of the `ContentPage`.And if you put it in a different location, it will not be displayed.

Just as follows:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Controls">
    <Shell.SearchHandler>
        <controls:AnimalSearchHandler 
                                      ... />
    </Shell.SearchHandler>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

So, you cannot use `Shell.SearchHandler` inside of `Grid`.

But as a workaround, you can use `SearchBar` instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiListViewMVVMApp.PrinterSettingsPage"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:appModel="clr-namespace:MauiListViewMVVMApp.Models"
             xmlns:appVM="clr-namespace:MauiListViewMVVMApp.ViewModels"
             Title="PrinterSettingsPage">
        

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Product" >
        <SearchBar Placeholder="Search items..."  Grid.Row="1"/>



    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

For more information, you can check :[SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/searchbar?view=net-maui-8.0).